# Removing starting and ending tags from a string in Perl

Tags: javascript, regex, perl, mason

I have a string like this :

```
<script>This String may contain other JS tags in between </script>
```

My requirement is to remove starting and ending Script tag from the string , If the string has some other tags in between , those should NOT be removed.

How can I do this in Perl ?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yes.. I tried using http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Strip/Strip.pm

but this would remove any other tags that might be present in the string

Comment: [Beware of the risks of parsing tags with regexes!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/2032064)

Answer (score 2):

Try the below perl one liner:

```
perl -lpe "s/<\/?script>//g" inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

In perl:

```
$string =~ s!<script[^>]*>|.*</\s*script>!!g;
```

Comment: This removes only the starting <script> , but not </script> at the end . Anyway , Thanks.. I'll understand this expression and find out the reason. Thanks

Comment: if the text within the script covers several lines, you may need to use a modifier; see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers

Comment: g - modifier will help

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code to remove the opening and the closing script tags.

```
"<script>This String may contain other JS tags in between </script>".replace(/^<script>|<\/script>$/g, "");
'This String may contain other JS tags in between '
```

**OR**

```
"foo <script>This String may contain other JS tags in between </script> foo".replace(/^((?:(?!<script>).)*)<script>(.*?)<\/script>((?:(?!<script>).)*)$/g, "$1$2$3");
'foo This String may contain other JS tags in between  foo'
```

Through perl,

```
$ echo 'foo <script>This String may contain other JS tags in between </script> foo' | perl -pe 's/^((?:(?!<script>).)*)<script>(.*?)<\/script>((?:(?!<script>).)*)$/\1\2\3/g'
foo This String may contain other JS tags in between  foo
```

Comment: "How can I do this in Perl ?" © ALBI

Answer (score 0):

In perl you can do a test to check if it matches your tags, and then do substitution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; 
use strict;

my $string = '<script>This String may contain other JS tags in between </script>';

if ( $string =~ /^(<script>).*(<\/script>)$/ ) {
$string =~ s/$1|$2//g;
}
print $string, "\n";
```

this will print:

```
This String may contain other JS tags in between
```

Comment: $string =~ s/^(<script>)|(<\/script>)$//g;  will also just do it.